# Display laravel retrun result in html table using jquery- Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel Blade I have a script for searching

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
        url: "{{ URL::asset('upload-panel/search')}}",
        data: dataString,
        dataType:"JSON",
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) { 
        var FinalResult=result.CallDetails
        num_rows = result.length;
        console.log(result)


        },error:function(x,e) {
            setTimeout(function() {searchPhoneCalls();}, 2000);
        }
    })
</script>
```

search function in controller returns is below

**return  json_encode($users);**

In console am getting the result as an array like below

```
0: {Short_name: "GO120762", Date: "21-01-2020"}
1: {Short_name: "GO120764", Date: "21-01-2020"}
2: {Short_name: "GO120766", Date: "21-01-2020"}
```

I want to display those result in a HTML  table  like below

```
+----------+------------+
| Name     | Date       |
+----------+------------+
| GO120762 | 21-01-2020 |
+----------+------------+
| GO120764 | 21-01-2020 |
+----------+------------+
| GO120766 | 21-01-2020 |
+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Use a foreach loop in your blade to parse the data from your controller.

Comment: how? thats my question @pr1nc3

Comment: here from docs : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: am getting result in ajax result. how to pass this  to laravel foreach loop? @Kusy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to deal with Laravel, it's pure HTML / jQuery "problem".

There is no such key named `CallDetails` exists in received JSON

You can build an array in your HTML :

```
<table id="table-search"></table>
```

And in your JS :

```
var $tableSearch = $('#table-search');
$tableSearch.html('');
//var FinalResult = result.CallDetails
result.forEach(function(row) {
    $tableSearch.append('<tr><td>'+ row.Short_name +'</td><td>'+ row.Date +'</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: Showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: @TestCheck remove `var FinalResult=result.CallDetails` line and check the answer. Eg.`var $tableSearch = $('#table-search');
$tableSearch.html('');
result.forEach(function(row) {
    $tableSearch.append('<tr><td>'+ row.Short_name +'</td><td>'+ row.Date +'</td></tr>');
});`

Comment: Yssss Its Working Thanks @Vincent Decaux @ Ritesh Khandekar

Answer (score 0):

In your blade:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

IN ajax script:

```
success: function(result) { 
    var FinalResult=result.CallDetails
    num_rows = result.length;
    console.log(result)

    $.each(FinalResult, function(index, value){
        $('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+value.Short_name+'</td><td>'+value.Date+'</td></tr>');
    });

 }
```

Comment: Still Console returns value but table doesnot

Comment: @TestCheck Can you add table HTML in blade?

Comment: @RiteshKhandekar     Here is the console  https://paste.pics/83M9H

Comment: @TestCheck can you replaced `$('tbody').append('<tr><td>+value.Short_name+</td><td>+value.Date+</td></tr>');`

Comment: @TestCheck Also add console inside a loop `console.log(value.Short_name)`.

Comment: Above answer gives me a solution. Thanks @AmitSenjaliya for your kind support

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
success: function(result) {
 var tableSearch = $('#table-search');
 tableSearch.html('');

 $.each(result, function(index, value){
    tableSearch.append('<tr><td>'+value.Short_name+'</td><td>'+value.Date+'</td></tr>');
});
}
```